# Count Total number of set bits for 2 given numbers

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

Question is Given - To Count Total number of set bits for 2 given numbers . For example take 2 and 3 as input . So 2 represents - 10 in binary form and 3 represents - 11 in binary form , So total number of set bits = 3.

My work -

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int bit(int n1, int n2){
    int count = 0;

    while(n1 != 0 && n2 != 0){
        if(n1 & 1 || n2 & 1) {
            count++;
        }
        n1 >> 1;
        n2 >> 1;
    }
    
    return count;
}


int main() {
    
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    
    cout << bit(a,b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
Expected Output - 3
```

So please anyone knows what i am doing wrong please correct it and answer it.

Comment: Just use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount (can compile to native CPU instruction directly)

Comment: Just a thought, it might be more correct to write the function to only take one argument and add the results: `bit(a) + bit(b)`. That said, there's no indication what your instructor actually wants.

Answer (score 2):

Why ask the question for 2 numbers if the intended combined result is just the sum of the separate results?

If you can use C++20, [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount) gives you the number of set bits in one unsigned variable.

If you can't use C++20, there is [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Construct one from your number and use its method [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count).

So your code becomes:

```
int bit(int n1, int n2) {
#if defined(__cpp_lib_bitops)
    return std::popcount(static_cast<unsigned int>(n1)) + std::popcount(static_cast<unsigned int>(n2));
#else
    return std::bitset<sizeof(n1)*8>(n1).count() + std::bitset<sizeof(n2)*8>(n2).count();
#endif
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GPKvrn6o3)

I'm not quite sure what happens if you give negative integers as input. I would do a check beforehand or just work with unsigned types from the beginning.

Comment: Re: Negative numbers. Both `std::popcount` and `std::bitset` are defined to only work for unsigned types as per their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong was shown in a (now deleted) answer by [Ankit Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11074646/ankit-kumar):

```
if(n1&1 || n2&1){
    count++;
}
```

> If a bit is set in both n1 and n2, you are including it only once, not twice.

What should you do, other than using C++20's [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount), is to write an algorithm<sup>1</sup> that calculates the number of bits set in **a** number and then call it **twice**.

Also note that you should use an unsigned type, to avoid implementation defined behavior of right shifting a (possibly) signed value.

---

<sup>1) I suppose that is the purpose of OP's exercise, everybody else shuold just use `std::popcount`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without a loop, no if and only 1 variable.

First OR the values together

```
int value = n1 | n2; // get the combinedd bits
```

Then divide value in bitblocks

```
value = (value & 0x55555555) + ((value >> 1) & 0x55555555);
value = (value & 0x33333333) + ((value >> 1) & 0x33333333);
value = (value & 0x0f0f0f0f) + ((value >> 1) & 0x0f0f0f0f);
value = (value & 0x00ff00ff) + ((value >> 1) & 0x00ff00ff);
value = (value & 0x0000ffff) + ((value >> 1) & 0x0000ffff);
```

This works for 32bit values only, adjust fopr 64bit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int noOfbits(int x)
{
int count =0;
while(x!=0 )
{
    if(x&1 )
    {
     count++;
    }
    x=x>>1;
   
}
return count;

}

int main()
{

int x,y;

cin>>x>>y;

//calling function for 
//first number

noOfbits(x);

//calling function for 
//second number

noOfbits(y);

cout<<noOfbits(x)+noOfbits(y);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) Please make your code more readable by adding some consistent indentation. (2) Why are you calling `noOfbits` *twice* for each variable?